# All-Wheel Drive/ 4WD system

Tags: subaru, jeep, 4wd, awd

Time has come to clear things out...
I would like to know the difference between a center differential and a transfer case.

I know that a transfer case engages the front axle with the rear axle in 4H and 4L.(correct me if I'm wrong) As far as I know, vehicles with transfer case are RWD.
Now when I thought about a center differential, I just thought of a differential (that typical circular one) in the center of the bottom of the car. When I had a chance to look underneath an AWD car, I found no "center differential".(Even though I saw a driveshaft and a rear axle)

But there are also vehicles with a transfer case that acts like a normal AWD car...so it confuses me overall!

So my question is: What does a center differential look like, and its location, and its function (like a transfer case)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The center differential in a typical Subaru transmission is housed inside of the main transmission case. For the MT models, these are typically viscous-coupling that control the torque split between the front and rear differentials (which may be open, viscous/clutch/Torsen LSD, etc.). The AT models may have different things that function as a center differential that I'm not as familiar with.

Some overview on the different AWD systems Subaru has:

> ## Center Differential with Viscous LSD
>
> In this AWD system, the center differential is implemented by a
>   bevel-gear, utilizing a mechanical viscous coupling device acting as
>   limited slip function. This type of differential is commonly known as
>   VLSD (Viscous Limited Slip Differential).
>
> [image: Subaru VLSD Center Differential]

In the above diagram, (10) is the center differential, and (11) are the viscous coupling plates.

> ## Active Torque Split + Multi-Plate Transfer Clutch
>
> This is the most common type of AWD in the market. In this system, a
>   multi-plate clutch pack acts as power coupling, and is responsible for
>   transfering power to the front wheels. The ECU uses multiple sensors’
>   input to determine the optimal torque split ratio, then it controls
>   the hydraulic lines to apply suitable pressure between the input and
>   output clutches, therefore achieving the goal of actively adjusting
>   front/rear torque distribution ratio.
>
> [image: Active Torque Split]
>
> ## Variable Torque Distribution (VTD)
>
> For this AWD system, Subaru installs a planetary gear-set as the
>   center differential, and uses a multi-plate clutch to implement the
>   limit slip functionality.
>
> This system is fundamentally different than the above #2 type. For the
>   VTD system, the power transmitted to front wheels is passed through
>   the planetary gear-set, not the clutch pack. The multi-plate clutch
>   only acts as limit-slip protection, and it will not kick in unless
>   wheel slip is happening.
>
> [image: Variable Torque Distribution]

In the above picture, (23) is the planetary gear differential, and (24) is the electronically controlled clutch-pack.

> ## Driver Controlled Center Differential (DCCD)
>
> The DCCD AWD system is specifically for the WRX STI (6MT). In fact it
>   is the VTD, plus an extra feature to let driver manually select
>   front/rear torque distribution, and both of the front/rear
>   differential are also LSD type. Default front/rear torque distribution
>   is 41:59; maximum adjustment ability is 50:50.
>
> [image: Double clutch-pack of DCCD]

The above picture depicts the two LSDs used in the DCCD. The electrical LSD allows the driver to adjust the torque bias between the front and rear in real-time. Here's [an official document from Subaru](http://youwheel.com/home/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Subaru_DCCD_Technical_EN.pdf) explaining the DCCD system in detail (ca. 2016).

[Source](http://youwheel.com/home/2016/08/07/subaru-awd-system-fully-explained/)

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. If you like my answer, feel free to upvote it (to the left of the answer). If it answers your question, feel free to accept it, but typical etiquette is to wait a couple days for others to create their own answers, then pick the most suitable for your question.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the tip! Would this website be the best and the fastest to ask any automotive questions?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's a dedicated Q&A site that looks for directed questions that aren't open-ended.